# isosurface tracking in high dimensions

Tags: dimensions, dimensional

how to trace isosurface on a higher dimensional space efficiently

Comment: How do you expect the solution to be represented ? I guess that your current approach gives you 3 curves, not a surface, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It gives surface not 3 just 3 curves. I want the set of isocost locations.

Comment: If you don't provide more info I can't help you.

Comment: given the static grid and cost C, i need the coordinate postions in the grid at which cost(pos) = C. I am not clear about what information you require. Can you clarify

Comment: There is an infinity of such points. If you just want all points on grid lines, fix the corresponding d-1 coordinates and find the intersection by binary search and linear (or better) interpolation on the remaining coordinate.

Comment: Does the [Marching Cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) algorithm fit your needs?

Comment: A walk over the cells the isosurface intersects is not dependent on the number of dimensions used. It is basically the same algorithm you can use to solve mazes; you just consider grid cells open if the isosurface intersects that cell (the 2ⁿ grid cell corner samples span the isosurface value), and closed otherwise. Visualizing/describing the isosurface within each cell is a separate issue, but almost always only uses the cost samples at the cell corners (2ⁿ samples total, for n dimensions).

Comment: Have you considered using body-centric cubic sampling for the cost function? By doubling the number of samples (in addition to `f(i,j,k,...)` you also sample `f(i+0.5,j+0.5,k+0.5,...)`) you increase the resolution for the isosurface samples (by almost half), but the number of intersections increases from `n(n-1)` to `n(n-1)2ⁿ` for `n` dimensions thus producing much more isosurface polygon mesh points, and you get rid of the ambiguous cases (especially the worst case, corner samples alternating beneath and above the isosurface level).

Answer (score 1):

You have a scalar cost function in *N* dimensions,

> *f*(*y*<sub>0</sub>, *y*<sub>1</sub>, .., *y<sub>N</sub>*) ∊ ℝ,   *y* ∊ ℝ

but sampled only in a regular rectangular grid,

> *y<sub>k</sub>* = *Ψ<sub>k</sub>* + *ψ<sub>k</sub>* *x<sub>k</sub>*,   constants *Ψ<sub>k</sub>* ∊ ℝ and *ψ<sub>k</sub>* ∊ ℝ, and grid coordinates *x<sub>k</sub>* ∊ ℕ

and the problem is to locate the isosurface(s) *i*,

> *f*(*y*<sub>0</sub>, *y*<sub>1</sub>, .., *y<sub>N</sub>*) = *C<sub>i</sub>*

The direct approach would be to just loop over each cell in the grid, and check if the current isosurface intersects the current cell, and if so, describe the part of the isosurface within the current cell. (Marching Cubes is one approach to describing how the isosurface intersects each grid cell.)

The restriction here is to use a *neighborhood based search* instead of examining every single cell.

OP had a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27258941) specifically for the 3D case, to which I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27550398) a link to example code, [grid.h](http://pastebin.com/hvhQLBu6) and [grid.c](http://pastebin.com/tFX4eGmG) (at Pastebin.com, because they were too long to include inline).

That implementation is completely different to OP's slicing method. Mine is a direct, simple walk over the grid cells intersecting the current isosurface. It caches the grid samples, and uses a separate map (one `char` per grid cell) to keep track which grid cells have been cached, walked, and/or pushed to a stack to be walked later. This approach is easily extended to more than three dimensions. Although the code is written for exactly three dimensions, the approach itself is not specific to three dimensions at all; all you need to do is to adjust the data structures to accommodate any (sensible) number of dimensions.

The isosurface walk itself is trivial. You start from any grid cell the isosurface intersects, then examine all 2*N* nearest neighbor cells to see if the isosurface intersects those too. In practice, you use a stack of grid cell locations to be examined, and a map of grid cell flags to avoid re-examining already examined grid cells.

Because the number of grid point samples per grid cell is 2*N*, my example code is not optimal: a lot of nearby grid points end up being evaluated to see if the neighboring grid cells do intersect the isosurface. (Instead of examining only the grid points delimiting the isosurface, grid points belonging to any grid cells surrounding the isosurface are examined.) This extra work grows exponentially as *N* increases.

A better approach would be to consider each of the 2*N* possible (*N*-1)-faces separately, to avoid examining cells the isosurface does not intersect at all.

In an *N*-dimensional regular rectangular grid, each cell is an *N*-dimensional cuboid, defined by the 2<sup>*N*</sup> grid points at the vertices (corners). The *N*-cuboid cells have *N*(*N*-1) two-dimensional faces, and 2*N* (*N*-1)-dimensional faces.

To examine each (*N*-1)-face, you need to examine the cost function at the 2<sup>*N*-1</sup> grid points defining that (*N*-1)-face. If the cost function at those points spans the isosurface value, then the isosurface intersects the (*N*-1)-face, and the isosurface intersects the next grid cell in that direction also.

There are two (*N*-1)-faces perpendicular to each axis. If the isosurface intersects the (*N*-1)-face closer to negative infinity, then the isosurface intersects the next grid cell along that axis towards negative infinity too. Similarly, if the isosurface intersects the (*N*-1)-face closer to positive infinity, then it also intersects the next grid cell along that axis towards positive infinity too. Thus, the (*N*-1)-faces are perfect for deciding which neighboring cells should be examined or not. This is true because the (*N*-1)-face is exactly the set of grid points the two cells share.

I'm very hesitant to provide example C code, because the example code of the same approach for the 3D case does not seem to have helped anyone thus far. I fear a longer explanation with 2- and 3-dimensional example images for illustration would be needed to describe the approach in easily understandable terms; and without a firm grasp of the logic, any example code would just look like gobbledygook.

Answer (score 1):

You are better using a library for 2 dimension you can try the conrec algorithm from Prof. Paul Bourke. It's similar to a marching cube.